# Does the back of the case for the Nikon SB-400 (SS-400) have a loop?

Tags: flash, equipment-protection

This is kind of a lame question, but I'm wondering if the back of the case for the Nikon SB-400 have a loop to carry it on a belt or strap. The model number for the case is SS-400 and looks like this:

http://www.pbase.com/image/88383398

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have an SB-400, just can't locate it at the moment!  Will update with a definitive answer once I've found it!  Almost certain that jaquer is correct and there isn't one.  It's a tiny unit, not much bigger than a pack of cigarettes, and the case is very snug. You can put the whole thing in a pocket, it's that small, or simply leave it on the camera.

Comment: Thanks. I don't really like answering my own questions, so I will mark yours as the correct one as soon as you confirm.

Comment: I am still looking for that little sucker.  Used it a few weeks ago, probably in a jacket pocket.  Haven't forgot, will update eventually!

Comment: I ended up buying the case. Just like j-g-faustus says up there: no loop. Thanks!

Comment: I have still not found it, I think someone must have borrowed it and I've forgotten. I think you should accept your own answer, I was no help in the end!

Comment: Found it!  No loop!  :)

Answer (score 3):

Nope, it looks like it doesn't. I ended up doing a YouTube search for SB-400 videos, to see if anyone mentioned it. I didn't find any videos explicitly talking about the cover, but these links briefly show the cover's back, and there is no loop visible:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O5ZpP2gv5uE#t=115s

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hv8Q92qMcuk#t=8s

Comment: I have one, and you're right: No loop.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm giving MikeW the  credit because I don't like to self-answer.